# Creating a windows service which will start on user log in

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have a exe of windows form application which is copied in AppData folder of each logged in user. Currenly that exe gets started after user log in but it takes lot of time to start. So I am thinking of developing a windows service which will invoke that exe as soon as the User logs in. I want to start that exe separately for each logged in user. 
 Am I going in right direction developing  a windows service if yes please tell me how to do that else what is ideal way to do this?

Comment: Why would the exe load faster if launched from a service?

Comment: In general, the right way for a service to interact with user sessions is for there to be a separate exe that's set to launch using the `Startup` menu when users log in, and which uses some form of RPC to communicate with the service - so if you were building this correctly, you'd be replacing a program that launches during log in and replacing it with... a different exe that launches during log in, and that is then told by the service to start the original program. That doesn't seem like a time saver to me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the service can only interact with the default desktop.

In a corporate network based on Active Directory, you would use a group policy to run the exe for each user.

On a stand-alone PC, you could set the startup programs for each user.